# How to match Photoshop canvas color to background of site?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpg, canvas

I'm building an e-commerce site and use a .JSX script to bulk resize images and add canvas if needed so the aspect ratio is 1:1

The problem is the default canvas color in Photoshop CC 2017 does not quite match the background of my site. For example, you can see clearly how the canvas color clearly doesn't blend in with the site background. What is the easiest way to change this canvas color so it isn't such an eye sore?

[image]

As requested, here is the JSX script I use:

```
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder to process"),
       fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(/\.(jpg|tif|psd|crw|cr2|nef|dcr|dc2|raw)$/i);

for(var i=0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        var doc = open(fileList[i]);
        if(doc.width !== doc.height) {
            if(doc.width > doc.height) {
                doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, doc.width)
            } else {
                doc.resizeCanvas(doc.height, doc.height)
            }
        }
        if((doc.width && doc.height) > 1000) {
            doc.resizeImage(1000, 1000);
        } else {
            doc.resizeImage(doc.width, doc.height);
        }

    doc.save();
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's my failing eyes, but I'm failing to see any difference in your image.

Comment: There is a very small difference but if you use a color picker you can see it. We would need to see the JSX file to know what is going on. Because Photoshop by default has a white background.

Comment: Let me add the contents of the JSX file, it isn't much

Comment: Okay I see a 002 difference across all channels R, G and B when examining. I kind of suspect this is due to jpg artifacts when resizing jpgs. Multiple jpg saves tends to result in more and more artifacts.

Comment: I can tell by eye on a calibrated setup. Something's going on in your export/colour management/profiles, perhaps… but those backgrounds are not truly flat, with a meter I see from 252 to 254. [by eye, I'm nowhere near that good ;)

Comment: @Adrift Why not solve this in CSS? It would seem cleaner to me, than extending the image files. And also this would allow to change the background color any time without rerendering all images.

Comment: @Scott: Gotcha, is there a way around this or .. ?

Comment: Don't save jpgs as jpgs. You *can* save jpgs as png generally without such degradation. And PNG -> PNG doesn't generally have the same problem as JPG -> JPG

Comment: @Scott: Thanks, wellI thought it was best practice to save things like product images as JPG but I guess that's not always true?

Comment: It really depends on what you need to do and the benefits/limitations of various formats.  There's no "one recipe" which works for everyone in every situation. There's nothing traditionally wrong with using jpgs.. but you are resaving images, which alters the usefulness of jpgs due to the lossy compression which increases degradation exponentially with each and every save. You *really* never want to save a jpg as a jpg.

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for the elaborate answer! Interestingly doing it with PNG seems to have the same issue. I'm wondering if this is just due to my monitor? I saved as PNG-24 BTW.

Comment: The original images don't have the variation in them do they? PNG traditionally **won't**  cause the same issues. **IF** it is indeed due to jpg compression. For what it's worth I can *visually* see the difference here.. and my monitor is calibrated regularly.. but .. well.. my eyes aren't what they used to be `:)`.

Comment: @Adrift If PNG is an option, you can also add a transparent background. This would totally avoid off-white tints.

Comment: @Scott: OK, thanks for the anecdotal info. Much appreciated Scott.

Comment: @AAGD: Would file size be much bigger than a JPG? If I went with transparent PNG 24?

Comment: Generally PNG24 is sometimes *slightly* larger, but it really depends upon the image data. I'd test a few and check. With those rugs and the patterns, there wasn't any great area benefiting from jpg compression. So, you might find PNG24 may be slightly *smaller* than jpgs. JPG compression works most in areas of broad similar color.

Comment: PNG filesizes are usually bigger than JPG, but these are tiny images. So the difference might not be dramatic. You can also optimize PNGs with a tool like ImageOptim to reduce the filesizes. But then this would not be a lossless process, like JPG, but with transparency.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your background color is the color you need: by default `Document.resizeCanvas()` uses it when the canvas is enlarged:

[image]

You can pass color with an AM command though, something like this:

```
resizeCanvas(600,600,{
    hue: 180,
    saturation: 100,
    brightness: 50
})

function resizeCanvas(width, height, color)
{
    if (color == undefined) color = {
        hue: 0,
        saturation: 0,
        brightness: 100
    };

    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Wdth'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), width);
    desc.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Hght'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), height);
    desc.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Hrzn'), charIDToTypeID('HrzL'), charIDToTypeID('Cntr'));
    desc.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Vrtc'), charIDToTypeID('VrtL'), charIDToTypeID('Cntr'));
    desc.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID('canvasExtensionColorType'), stringIDToTypeID('canvasExtensionColorType'), charIDToTypeID('Clr '));
    var descColor = new ActionDescriptor();
    descColor.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('H   '), charIDToTypeID('#Ang'), color.hue);
    descColor.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('Strt'), color.saturation);
    descColor.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('Brgh'), color.brightness);
    desc.putObject(stringIDToTypeID('canvasExtensionColor'), charIDToTypeID('HSBC'), descColor);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('CnvS'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of resizeCanvas()
```